# How to add HTML Editor to Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-wtp

I just upgraded to Eclipse Kepler, the non-J2EE version. The HTML Editor is missing. I read elsewhere that I could install the "Web Page Editor", which I did, but the system now generates all kinds of errors when building my project. Apparently it can't find some JSF classes. I have no interest in using JSF.

The Web Page Editor install did include the HTML Editor, but it was so much trouble I had to uninstall. How do I get my old HTML Editor back?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Alternatively, you can just install the "**HTML Editor**" from the WST package (the same one provided in Java EE Edition) in Eclipse 4.x, just by looking for "HTML Editor" in the marketplace (but, indeed, i haven't been able to found it in the "install new software").

On my side i prefer to work on Eclipse "Java Edition" most of the time (just adding the few additionnal features i really need).

[image]

Comment: Don't do that any more. That Marketplace entry is very out of date. Look for the Eclipse Web Developer Tools.

Comment: In fact this does not work at all in newer releases.

Answer (score 14):

Go to Install New Softwares-> Select your version eclipse repo. eg Mars - http://download.eclipse.org/releases/mars -> Expand Web,XML, JAVA EE option -> Install Eclipse Web Developer Tools

Comment: For Eclipse Oxygen, this is perfect.

Comment: Works for Luna too (legacy project)

Answer (score 6):

I have used **CodeMix** for a while and it's a wonderful tool, it can easily install as a plugin and a wide tools will be available like HTML Validation, Emmet, CSS IntelliSense, Snippets, take a look in this site https://www.genuitec.com/sox/tech/html5-with-codemix/

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue once, and I tried a HTML editor addon for eclipse, but haven't found one that's any better than the one that comes with the Java EE edition of eclipse.

I suggest you download the Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers.

Comment: yes best is to download Eclipse IDE for Java EE developers or Web Developers

Answer (score 1):

You may want to install Eclipse Web Developer Tools
[image: Web Developer Toools]

Bet you after edit HTML you will have to edit CSS and JavaScrip too