# indenting tags within <head></head> in eclipse

Tags: html, eclipse, indentation, auto-indent

I need Eclipse(Kepler) to indent html tags within `<head>...</head>` when I hit **Ctrl+Shift+F**

Currently, this:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Insert title here</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function func() {
console.log("Hello world");
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p onclick="func()">Some text</p>
</body>
</html>
```

becomes this when I hit the key combination.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Insert title here</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function func() {
        console.log("Hello world");
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <p onclick="func()">Some text</p>
</body>
</html>
```

I need everything within `<head>...</head>` to be indented and also all the tags within `<html>...</html>`.

Ideally this way:

```js
function func() {
  console.log("Hello world");
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Insert title here</title>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    /* function */
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <p onclick="func()">Some text</p>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Following link seems to have what you are looking for:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17892094/how-to-add-html-editor-to-eclipse

Comment: use vscode instead :D

Answer (score 1):

You could try to go to:
Window > Preferences > Web > HTML Files > Editors.

Add/Remove what you want to indent from the inline field. From what I saw it doesn't include the head tag, so try adding in the list.

Comment: Pointless answer as either having or not having (default) head in the list doesn't change the way the indenting is done.

Comment: Indentetion worked correctly with the above. Instead of saying pointless answer, provide another solution.

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not produce the formatting requested by the OP. There does not appear to be a way to answer this question using Eclipse Kepler.