# How can I view the html source of a response webpage rendered inside Eclipse?

Tags: java, html, eclipse

I am running a servlet web application on tomcat inside eclipse Neon.

Eclipse renders and displays a response webpage to me, but I would like to view the html source of the response webpage. In Firefox, when I right click anywhere in a webpage, I can select to view the source of the webpage, but that doesn't work in Eclipse. I wonder how to do that in Eclipse?  I googled "eclipse view webpage html source", but I didn't find any solution. Maybe I miss something.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you might solve your problem using some extra plugin.
This might also be a [dupplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38312507/how-can-i-modify-html-source-using-an-eclipse-plugin)